# How to script p4 change changelist creation with marshalled python

Tags: python, marshalling, perforce

I am trying to script creation of a new p4 changelist using the -G global option.  This in combination with the -i command flag should allow me to pass in the changelist description through stdin as a marshaled python dictionary. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere that p4 documents the format of this code.

If i look at an existing changelist using marshaled dictionaries I see this:

```
>>> argx=["/usr/bin/p4","-G", "change", "-o", "12345"]
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(argx, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> c=p.communicate()
>>> c
>>> marshal.loads(c[0])
{'Status': 'pending', 'code': 'stat', 'Description': 'test\t\n', 'Client': 'myclient', 'User': 'me', 'Date': '2015/02/18 18:36:34', 'Type': 'public', 'Change': '12345'}
```

So I tried creating one this way:

```
>>> x={'Change': 'new', 'Status': 'new', 'Description': "p4test"}
>>> y=marshal.dumps(x)
>>> args=["/usr/bin/p4","-G", "-d", "/tmp", "change", "-i"]
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> c=p.communicate(y)
>>> marshal.loads(c[0])
{'generic': 34, 'code': 'error', 'data': 'Invalid marshalled data supplied as input.\n', 'severity': 3}
```

(which is not very helpful)
But if I look at the un-unmarshalled return I see embedded in it:

('{s\x04\x00\x00\x00codes\x05\x00\x00\x00errors\x04\x00\x00\x00datas+\x00\x00\x00Invalid marshalled data supplied as input.\ns\x08\x00\x00\x00severityi\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00generici"\x00\x00\x000{s\x04\x00\x00\x00codes\x05\x00\x00\x00errors\x04\x00\x00\x00datas@\x00\x00\x00**Error in change specification.\nMissing required field \'Change\'**.\ns\x08\x00\x00\x00severityi\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00generici\x04\x00\x00\x000', '')

So 1. There is an incompatibility in the way the message is marshaled and unmarshaled, I'm not seeing the specific error message, but there is something wrong with my 'Change' field format, 
or 2.  The missing required field message is a red herring caused by a dirty buffer in p4's marshaling code.

Either way I can't figure out how to do this.  Any suggestions? I'm trying to avoid having to introduce the p4 python API as it *should* be unnecessary considering how easy scripting most things (that don't involve editors) is in P4.  I'm going to start investigating that now, however, as I've already done way too much trial an error with this.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the primitive Python marshalling support in the p4 command line works for output, but not input -- it'll take "tagged" server output and translate it into a Python marshalled dictionary, but it won't go back the other way and turn a Python dictionary into the formatted spec that "p4 change -i" expects.  I think using the P4Python API (which it sounds like you're already investigating) is going to end up being the easiest solution, since that includes support for manipulating Perforce specs.

Comment: I agree that the marshaling for import is probably not implemented well.  Since this was a convenience script for internal use I just required that the user create the changelist manually and submitted it manually, Since the script could potentially change a lot of files it's not a bad thing that the user is more aware of the changelist and what is and isn't getting changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you only have to change you `dumps` call to specify the version of the data format, like this:

```
y=marshal.dumps(x, 0)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html#marshal.version for details on the marshal module data format version.

The Perforce Knowledge Base has some information on this also, but you must know what to search for to find it! I stumbled on the same problem a few years ago and spent days to fix the problem.

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3518/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle

> When using "marshal.dump()" in Python 2.4 or later, you must specify version "0" of the dump format or P4 cannot understand the data that is being sent.

I just tested it and I can successfully create a new changelist with a manually-constructed dictionary passed as input.

Comment: Thanks! Don't have time to test right now but given the citation I'm going to accept this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue as well while trying to create a client using a marshaled dict to supply the form data - even while providing version 0 to dumps.

Upgrading the version of p4 command line tool to Rev. P4/NTX64/2015.1/1415928 (2016/07/25) worked.

Was on Rev. P4/NTX64/2014.2/962050 (2014/11/13)